# XSLT transform to multiple complex types within for loop

Tags: xslt, xsd

I have a requirment to transform a XML with the below structure

```
<CustomerStatements>
 <CustomerStatement>
  <Name>ABC</Name>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Amt>10</Amt>
 </CustomerStatement>
 <CustomerStatement>
  <Name>ABC</Name>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Amt>20</Amt>
 </CustomerStatement>
 <CustomerStatement>
  <Name>XYZ</Name>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <Amt>30</Amt>
 </CustomerStatement>
 <CustomerStatement>
  <Name>XYZ</Name>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <Amt>40</Amt>
 </CustomerStatement>
</CustomerStatements>
```

To

```
<Customers>
 <Customer>
  <Name>ABC</Name>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Amounts>
   <Amount>10</Amount>
   <Amount>20</Amount>
  </Amounts>
 </Customer>
 <Customer>
  <Name>XYZ</Name>
  <Id>2</Id>
   <Amount>30</Amount>
   <Amount>40</Amount>
 </Customer>
</Customers>
```

I tried using a for loop and taking the name into a variable to compare the name in the next record, but this doesn't work. Can you any one help me with a sample XSLT psudo code.

Thanks

Comment: Have you got any XSLT to show at all?

Comment: If you are using XSLT 1.0 look for 'Muenchian grouping' - for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381339/standard-muenchian-grouping-xslt

Comment: I'm not sure why this questions was downvoted - you provided exactly what most individuals like to see in a well formatted question. +1 Please see my answer for both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 solutions.

Comment: @ABach: I downvoted the question because it is a grouping problem that has been asked already countless times here - a quick search produces already a lot of almost identical questions and answers.

Comment: @MiMo - I completely understand and empathize with your point. That said, users that come here -- especially novice ones -- need responsible answers to their questions in order to proceed. I want to give the OP the benefit of the doubt: I trust he/she will learn from this question and my subsequent answer.

Answer (score 1):

**I. When this XSLT 1.0 solution:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key 
    name="kCustByNameId"
    match="CustomerStatement"
    use="concat(Name, '+', ID)" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <Customers>
      <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="CustomerStatement[
          generate-id() = 
          generate-id(key('kCustByNameId', concat(Name, '+', ID))[1])]" />
    </Customers>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CustomerStatement">
    <Customer>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Name|ID" />
      <Amounts>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('kCustByNameId', concat(Name, '+', ID))/Amt">
          <Amount>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
          </Amount>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Amounts>
    </Customer>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied to the OP's original XML:**

```
<CustomerStatements>
  <CustomerStatement>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Amt>10</Amt>
  </CustomerStatement>
  <CustomerStatement>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Amt>20</Amt>
  </CustomerStatement>
  <CustomerStatement>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Amt>30</Amt>
  </CustomerStatement>
  <CustomerStatement>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Amt>40</Amt>
  </CustomerStatement>
</CustomerStatements>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Customers>
  <Customer>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Amounts>
      <Amount>10</Amount>
      <Amount>20</Amount>
    </Amounts>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Amounts>
      <Amount>30</Amount>
      <Amount>40</Amount>
    </Amounts>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

The primary thing to look at here is [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), which is the generally accepted method for grouping problems in XSLT 1.0.

**II. Here's a more compact XSLT 2.0 solution:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
     <Customers>
       <xsl:for-each-group select="CustomerStatement" group-by="ID">
         <Customer>
           <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]/Name|current-group()[1]/ID" />
           <Amounts>
             <xsl:for-each select="current-group()/Amt">
               <Amount>
                 <xsl:apply-templates />
               </Amount>    
             </xsl:for-each>
           </Amounts>
         </Customer>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
     </Customers>
   </xsl:template>      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this case, notice XSLT 2.0's use of the [for-each-group](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group) element, which eliminates the need for the sometimes-verbose and potentially confusing Muenchian Grouping method.

Comment: the Novatchev is strong in you.

Comment: Being a big fan of XSLT, I say the more the merrier.